# How can I make a TextBox accepts only numeric values in WinUI 3?

Tags: c#, winui-3

I have a `TextBox` which I use in Settings page of my app. Now, this textbox should only accept/display digits. There are several examples and solutions for this problem however, none of them work for WinUI 3 as they are mostly from 5-10 years ago.

`KeyPress` event does not exists in WinUI 3 `TextBox`. While looking for alternatives I saw `KeyDown` event however this event arguments are different and `KeyRoutedEventArgs` do not contain any property like `KeyChar`.

The example code I found that's applicable for WPF applications:

```
private void txtbox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar)) 
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

How can I achieve this behaviour in WinUI 3 `TextBox`?

Comment: The closest is probably NumberBox https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.xaml.controls.numberbox you can still enter invalid chars but they will be removed on focus change. Source (WinUI2.8) is here https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/tree/main/dev/NumberBox

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Link Hylia's answer was somehow correct in achieving the behaviour requested. I expanded on that answered by:

1. Changed the event used. The `KeyDown` or `TextChanged` events were asynchronous events and would not block the entered input to appear on the screen. I changed this to `TextChanging` event which is run synchronously and before the `TextBox.Text` is rendered. Using this method, I can control the text before its rendered and improve UX.
2. Instead of undoing, I now do just remove the char entered from the text and pass it back to the `TextBox`.
3. I put the cursor back to where it was before so that the user can continue typing from where they left.

The code can be found below:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanging(TextBox sender, TextBoxTextChangingEventArgs args)
{
    var currentPosition = textBox1.SelectionStart - 1;
    var text = ((TextBox)sender).Text;
    
    var regex = new Regex("^[0-9]*$");

    if(!regex.IsMatch(text))
    {
        var foundChar = Regex.Match(textBox1.Text, @"[^0-9]");
        if(foundChar.Success)
        {
            textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text.Remove(foundChar.Index, 1);
        }
                
        textBox1.Select(currentPosition, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is a workaround. well done.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `InputScope`!

You can find a [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.textbox.inputscope?view=winrt-22621) from the Microsoft docs.

Here's an example from Microsoft:

```xml
<TextBox Header="Telephone Number" InputScope="TelephoneNumber"/>
```

You can also do further verifications in the code-behind by listening to the `TextChanged` event:

```
<TextBox TextChanged="OnTextChanged" />

<!-- In your code-behind file -->

private void OnTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // Get the current text of the TextBox
    var text = ((TextBox)sender).Text;

    // Use a regular expression to only allow numeric values
    var regex = new Regex("^[0-9]*$");

    // If the text does not match the regular expression, undo the change
    if (!regex.IsMatch(text))
    {
        ((TextBox)sender).Undo();
    }
}
```

---

Edit:

In WinUI 3, you can use [KeyDown](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.xaml.uielement.keydown?view=windows-app-sdk-1.2) event too.

It's very similar to the way you did in WPF:

```
<TextBox KeyDown="OnKeyDown" />

private void OnKeyDown(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Check if the key pressed is a numeric key
    if (!((e.Key >= VirtualKey.Number0 && e.Key <= VirtualKey.Number9) || (e.Key >= VirtualKey.NumberPad0 && e.Key <= VirtualKey.NumberPad9)))
    {
        // If the key is not numeric, cancel the event and prevent the key from being entered
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Couple of things; I've set the `InputScope` to `Digits` however I can still type letters and characters other than digits. After that I tried your event however this completely deletes the box if a non-digit is typed. If it's the first character, thats fine however if its lets say `124552a` then it removes all the content, how can this be changed so that only the last character typed is removed?

Comment: Hello Link! I just tried your KeyDown event code however it had no effect at all (not even removed any char or effect on the box), https://i.imgur.com/Ovn4ZOf.png

Comment: Update. I'm now using the `TextChanging` event which occurs synchronously before the text is rendered. This helps with the UX. I'm working on fixing the "deleting entire text instead of last entry" issue.